# How to make URL redirection for partially dynamic URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo, redirect

I would like to create a redirection rule which will always redirect a user to specified URL, for instance:

from `http://www.team.com/team/player/5/1.html`

to `http://www.team.com/jose-garcia.html`

The number between `/player/` and `/1.html` is dynamic. I would like to make redirection regardless from the number that is set there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?team\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^team/player/\d+/1\.html$ /jose-garcia.html [L,NC,R=302]
```

`\d+` will match any number between `team/player/` and `/1.html`.